# Is it possible to use c# variable in css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Is there a way to use a session variable in CSS style such as to set width % dynamically.

```
    width:<%Convert.ToString(Session["DaysAvailable"]);%>%;
```

Comment: If the style is embedded in the HTML, sure. If it's a separate .css file, no.

Comment: If this sort of thing is important to your project, you might want to look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @JB11 confirmed. Here's a working example.

1. The div's width is set to 25% on `PageLoad()` only.
2. It's set to 75% on button `Click()` event.

**SessionCSS.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SessionCSS.aspx.cs" Inherits="SessionCSS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>    
    <style>
        .my-class{
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            width: <%= Session["DaysAvailable"].ToString() %>%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    

        <div class="my-class">
            Days available
        </div>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateDays" runat="server" Text="Update days" OnClick="btnUpdateDays_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**SessionCSS.cs (code behind)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SessionCSS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if( !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["DaysAvailable"] = 25;
        }
    }

    protected void btnUpdateDays_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["DaysAvailable"] = 75;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Note:This work only when CSS is directly inside the Page Markup and not in external Stylesheet.